# Device that uses NAT internally - how to avoid conflicting with connection to internet?

Tags: networking, routing, nat

I am building a device that has two Linux computers (raspberry pis) connected via cabled ethernet. One of them, the "outer" pi, has a wifi to the outside world. Both need to connect out, so the "outer" pi is being set up as a DHCP/NAT host with the cable connecting the two being a private two-computer network. The two pis need to be able to communicate even when the public wifi is absent - any internet operations can be delayed until the public wifi returns, but I can't wait for the public wifi to be present before I configure the private network and get the two pis talking to each other. So far, this all works well.

My question is this: If I set up my private network to have a 192.168.0.x subnet, for example, what happens if I join a public wifi that uses the same subnet? Routing on the outer pi would get hairy because both its networks will have the same subnet. I could use a subnet that is less common than 192.168.0.x, but don't know a legit non-routing address block that will never be used on a public wifi (I have no control over the public wifi, my device must work no matter how the customer's network is set up).

Do I have to listen for changes in the public wifi and reconfigure my private network as needed? If so, what is the cleanest way to let the "inner" pi know that it needs to get a new IP address and routing table? Or is there a better way that lets me set up a network that will work regardless of how the public wifi is configured. I've considered doing something really weird, like putting the two devices at 127.0.1.0 and 127.0.1.1, knowing that 127.x.x.x is reserved for loopback and thus won't ever be used by the public wifi, but an ugly hack like that seems likely to cause problems so I'd rather avoid it if possible.

Thanks. Apologies if this question doesn't belong on superuser - I've already been bounced out of stackoverflow (not a coding question) and network engineering (not a question about enterprise networks), hopefully this is the right home for it!

Comment: You cant guatantee *never* but you can make IP conflict less likely by using a tightish subnet in a less common range - eg 172.19.253.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 - there are 3 ranges set aside for end-user NAT (rfc1918) - 10.x.x.x 192.168.x.x and 172.16-31.x.x  - The last is -in my experience - the least commonly known/used.

Comment: It's just a risk of using this kind of setup, and you cannot guarantee no wifi overlaps with your subnet. I'd suggest copy Docker and use `172.17.0.0`. Note that 127.0.0.0 is local-host only, and can't be used for dhcp.

Comment: Devices on your private network don't need to know anything of changes on the Internet side of the device they are connecting to - they send everything they dont know to the upstream device through the default gateway.

Comment: Not sure if it would be a bad idea, but you may also consider "abusing" the CGNAT block (`100.64.0.0/10`). Besides, regardless of whichever block you pick, if this set up is not going to be "expanded", you really just need a `/30` for your private LAN, which is just 4 addresses. (On at least some OSes you can even use only 2 arbitrary addresses for a "point-to-point" setup.) Since one seldom need to access other client hosts in a public WiFi, it means you have even lower chance to get into trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RFC 1918 defines the IPv4 address ranges reserved for private use, such as behind a NAT. It defines the following three ranges:

- 10.0.0.0/8: 10.0.0.0–10.255.255.255
- 172.16.0.0/**12**: 172.16.0.0–172.**31**.255.255
- 192.168.0.0/16: 192.168.0.0–192.168.255.255

You're right that any RFC 1918 private address range *could* be in use on someone's network, and thus you could have a conflict if you hard-code your RPi setup to any one part of those ranges. So you're right that you'll have to look at what IPv4 address/subnet your outer RPi is assigned, and if it happens to conflict with the default private subnet your RPi setup uses, you'll need to renumber your RPi setup's private network.

Based on anecdotal experience, it seems few networks make use of the 172.16.0.0/12 range, and even fewer realize that it's a /12, so the second octet can be not just 16, anything from 16–31. So if you want a low chance at conflicts, pick something in the 172.17.0.0—172.31.255.255 range.

DHCP does not provide a way for the server to notify clients that their old leases have suddenly become invalid. But clients will automatically try to renew their lease if their link goes down and comes back up, so if the two RPi's are directly connected via an Ethernet cable without a hub or switch in between, you could have your "outer" RPi temporarily drop link on its Ethernet port (turn off its Ethernet port), so that the "inner" RPi sees its link go down, so that the inner RPi's DHCP client process will try to renew the lease as soon as the link comes back up, which will provide an opportunity for the outer RPi's DHCP server to refuse to renew the old lease, causing the inner RPi to ask for a new lease, allowing the outer RPi's DHCP server to serve it a new lease from the new subnet.

If you wanted to avoid these IPv4 DHCP lease hassles, you could consider using IPv6 link-local addressing on the private link between your two RPis instead of using IPv4. You'd probably want to run something like a NAT64 gateway process on your outer RPi, so that your inner RPi can still reach IPv4 resources on the wider Internet, even though your inner RPi won't have an IPv4 address of its own.

Comment: Thanks Spiff! That confirms my thoughts and the information on how to force a renewal of the DHCP lease is helpful. @TomYan said something that got me thinking too, about how you could skip DHCP on the private network and hardcode addresses. I could hardcode IPs from the 169.254.0.0/16 link-local block. This is meant as temporary IP when you want to use DHCP but can't reach the server, so it's not 100% legit, but the internet router would never be in that block. They SHOULD work out OK. I'll probably try both - if the DHCP restart works smoothly I'll use that, with 169.254 as my fallback.